# Download/RIP all MAPPED JavaScript from website

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

I have a minified JavaScript file (`.js`), and a JavaScript Source Map (`.js.map`). I know it is possible to download the mapped source code files one-by-one from the browser console (Firefox and Chrome), but I'm looking at an enormous code base; Downloading one-by-one would take forever.

Is there any way to get the original javascript from these two files locally? without setting up another server?
OR
Is there a way to bulk-download the *mapped* javascript?

Why? I'm doing a security assessment for my target website. Simulate an attacker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nvm I ended up using [unmap](https://github.com/chbrown/unmap). Works like a charm.